# How to avoid 404 error with Angular 7 Single Page Application on Wildfly

Tags: angular, wildfly, single-page-application

I have a front-end project as single page application (SPA) built with Angular 7, which consumes a Java REST API hosted on Wildfly (there are other projects on the same server). We recently moved this SPA from Apache to Wildfly to serve it under HTTPS. Everything works fine except when the user hits F5 or refreshes the page any other way; in this case he or she falls into a 404 error, since SPAs expect the navigation to stay at index.html all the time.

For instance, if I access *[server:port]/myspa* it loads correctly and redirects me to *[server:port]/myspa/login*. But if I am already in *[server:port]/myspa/login* and refresh the page, I get stuck in 404.

I've already tried some configurations in *standalone.xml* that didn't work, like setting a filter inside **undertow** subsystem like bellow:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
    ...
    <server name="default-server">
        ...
        <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
            ...
            <filter-ref name="spa-to-index" predicate="equals(%s,404)" />            
        </host>
    </server>
    ...
    <filters>
        ...        
        <rewrite name="spa-to-index" redirect="true"
            target="http://localhost:8080/myspa/" />
    </filters>
</subsystem>
```

Does anyone know how to redirect requests for [server:port]/myspa/* to the index.html?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Ok @DeborahK, maybe Nginx can help me with this matter. I´ll run some tests and bring results soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an easy way that I found to solve this was: installing **grunt.js** and **grunt war**.

```
npm install -g grunt -cli
npm install grunt-war --save-dev
```

Create the **Gruntfile.js** file inside the root folder of the project with the following content (do not forget to replace [myapp] occurrencies with your own project info)

```
module.exports = function ( grunt ) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-war' );

    var taskConfig = {
        war: {
            target: {
                options: {
                    war_verbose: true,
                    war_dist_folder: 'warFile',   // Folder path seperator added at runtime. 
                    war_name: '[myapp]',      // .war will be appended if omitted 
                    webxml_welcome: 'index.html',
                    webxml_webapp_extras: ['<error-page><location>/index.html</location></error-page>'], 
//redirect the errors pages to index.html
                    webxml_display_name: '[myapp]'
                },
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        cwd: 'dist/[myapp]', //the folder where the project is located
                        src: ['**'],
                        dest: ''
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };

    grunt.initConfig( taskConfig );
};
```

Then run the command:

```
grunt war
```

This will package the Angular application inside a .war file, and you can deploy it normally on Wildfly, and refreshing the page will work as expected.

Comment: I was trying everything and nothing was working. Always getting 404 or 500 no matter what I tried. Finally setting `welcome-file` to `index.html` and `error-page.location` to `/index.html` fixed the issues. I just don't understand why one needs a different path than the other.

Thank you for this

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of grunt. Simply add this content into `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
     version="4.0">
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```